# How to delete Elasticsearch clusters

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing

How can I delete ES clusters?

Every time I start ES locally, it brings my indexes back to cluster state, which is now up to 33 and I believe taking up much of my RAM (8 GBs).

I only have 3 very small indexes, the biggest being just about 3 MBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply delete all the indices that you do not need. Have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html

Comment: thanks man!, didn't know it was that easy. Sometimes I just don't have a whole lot of time to search for answers and it can be much quicker just asking a question here!

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada I have fixed the URL now. Thanks for flagging.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the index that you want
For example, get your indices

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v=
```

I got an index called **web**, for example, just delete it

```
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:9200/web
```

See more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html)